# How can I get a working corrplot for my data?

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to get the corrplot for my data variables which are a combination of binary, continuous and categorical variables. However, when I run this code, it keeps giving me errors. The error when i load my data frame, called df2, is: Error in corrplot(df2) : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!. How can I solve this?

When I compute the correlation I also get that for certain variables, I only receive NA's, even though they are numeric and integer values [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzZB7.png).

Attached an example of my data variables, where hh_code is the column used for identification: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1tkI.png)

How can I get the correlation between variables for my data in R? Thanks!

Comment: The commands I used: cor(df2)
corrplot(df2)

Comment: Correlation is not defined on categorial data. You should also get the error e.g. Can't combine foo <character> and bar <double>.

Comment: I do not see any attached data.

Comment: @Bernhard hey, thanks for your reply. If you press on the 1 and 2 in blue, the link should take you to the screenshot of my data.

Comment: @danlooo does that mean i have to run the corrplot separately for binary, categorical and for my continuous variables? What would you suggest as i need to see if there is multicollinearity in my data set.

Comment: multicollinearity implies numerical variables. I think you are looking for effect sizes of  statistical dependency instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table in which some columns are numeric and others are categorical, you can use the function `GGally::ggpairs` to get an overview about the associations between these variables:

```r
library(GGally)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'GGally':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2
data <- ggplot2::mpg[c(1,3,4,7,8)]
ggpairs(data)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you need a little bit more rigour, you can use statistical tests to get significant relationships between columns / variables (if their assumptions hold):

| covariate x | outcome y | test | R function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| numeric | numeric | Person correlation | `cor.test(x,y, method = "pearson")` |
| binary | numeric | t test | `t.test(x, y)` |
| ordinal (ordered factor) | ordinal (ordered factor) | Spearman correlation | `cor.test(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method="spearman")` |
| categorial (many levels) | numeric | ANOVA | `anova(lm(y ~ x))` |